# Json object in post not recognized as object in web api

Tags: c#, angular, dapper, webapi

I have an angular client and want to execute a get request to my web api backend to get a list of items from the underlying Dapper Db Wrapper. Dapper allows me to pass in parameters as an anonymous object which would in csharp look like this:

```
connection.GetList<T>(new {myParam1:"a", myParam2: true});
```

What I want to achieve is, to create this parameter object in my angular frontend and pass it in a post request to the server which would then pass it on to the GetList function. The problem here is that the web api does not deserialize it as an (anonymous) object, but rather and IEnumerable of JTokens?

My web api signature is this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyFunction([FromBody]dynamic whereCond)
```

I have also tried to pass the object as string wrapped in an outer object like so (angular client):

```
this.migController.MigrationGetMigrationReports({whereCond: JSON.stringify({NotMigrated: true, MissingTargetFiles: 0})})
```

and then on the server I manually deserialize it as JObject:

```
string obj = whereCond.whereCond;
dynamic pObj = JObject.Parse(obj);
```

But this results in the exact same result: pObj is an IEnumerable and therefore I get an error message from the GetList call:

> An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context

can anybody help?

Comment: You have a design problem. Your client should not be aware of your storage technology. Client should receive data and display it, and post data to the server. How the server interacts with the database is not the concern of the client.

Comment: I would suggest the overhead of creating a model to store the parameters and not use `dynamic` is not that high and would solve your problem

Comment: I have thought about creating a model for parameters, but i have many lists with many columns and i would need to create parameter objects with all possible columns plus default values...i thought there would be something more generic, similar to the OData interface, but lightweight...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question turned out rather simple:

```
            dynamic pObj = JObject.Parse(obj).ToObject<ExpandoObject>();
```

I had to cast it as ExpandoObject not just dynamic.

@Tsahi: this is not a design problem. My intention was to provide the server with parameters (filter) which is a quite common task for a client to reduce the dataset to be transferred. We could debate a standard way how to provide these parameters, however. In my special case the most practical way is the anonymous object.